# What was the common usage of the term "alien" around 1977?

Tags: aliens, languages, alien-franchise, alien-1979, title-explanation

The *Alien* movie was released in 1979. If you walked up to the average person on the street in 1977 and asked them to think of an alien, what is the first thing that would come to mind: would it be 'a monster from outer space' or 'a foreigner in a sovereign land without proper visas'?

Another way of posing the question would be: was a title of *Alien* for a space monster movie novel and clever in 1979?

Comment: Can people please explain their downvotes? I didn't downvote. However, maybe you'll find better responses to this in English language SE?  Btw, The word alien doesn't necessarily mean a monster. It can also mean a benevolent extraterrestrial.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. “Alien” has never meant “space monster” specifically. The first recorded use of “alien” as a noun meaning “extraterrestrial” in the Oxford English Dictionary is from 1931. Does that help at all?

Comment: @anaranjada Yes, that is very good. Should be an answer.

Comment: @anaranjada Good. And people who don't have access to the OED can findthat 1931 quotation at the [Science Fiction Citations](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/10) site.

Comment: I don't understand the question, either: Indeed, a film title like "The Space Monster" might seem a little silly - which is why the 1979 film was not named "The Space Monster", but "Alien". And of course, as @anaranjada said, "alien" is not meant to mean "space monster, but simply "extraterrestrial". Are we maybe talking about at a translated title of the film that indeed means "space monster"?

Comment: So... the real question should have been _when did "alien" start to mean "extraterrestrial" rather than simply "foreign"_.

Comment: Is the term _alien_ known to mean ‘space monster’ **after** the 1979 film?

Comment: Also, I want to state here for the record that while "The Space Monster" is a silly title for a film, so is "The Thing". Oh, and there is a 2010 film called "Monsters".

Comment: Considering the 50s and 60s were the golden age of the alien invasion genre, I'd go out on a limb and say most people that you would bump into on the street grew up with "alien" meaning "extraterrestrial". Monster is probably pushing it, but based on stuff like The Blob, not outside possibility.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was six in 1977 when Star Wars and Close Encounters were released, and even as a 6-year-old I knew the term "alien" meaning "extraterrestrial," and did not know of the other usage for many years.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English language historical usage, not science fiction.

Answer (score 8):

*"If you walked up to the average person on the street in 1977 and asked them to think of an alien, what is the first thing that would come to mind: would it be 'a monster from outer space' or 'a foreigner in a sovereign land without proper visas'?"*

I was born in 1964, hence 13 in 1977. To me and all my contemporaries the word "alien" definitely meant "space alien". I distinctly remember being rather proud of myself for even *knowing* that the word also had an older meaning of "foreigner".

On the other hand, my Penguin English Dictionary first published in August 1965 defines the noun alien thus: "foreigner, *esp* one living in one's own country and not naturalized." Not a tentacle in sight.

*Added later:* I was 15 when the film "Alien" came out. It was X-rated so I couldn't go and see it, but I do recall a hearing a graphic second-hand description of the "chestburster" scene from a friend whose older brother had seen the film. I do *not* remember ever giving a thought to the title.

(Sorry for the late edit. That last bit was something I had to get off my chest.)

Comment: Ah.. the days when X-rating meant something different (which is exactly the reason why the porn industry invented their own made-up rating of XXX)

Answer (score 2):

From the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alien):
Alien [...]

- too different from something to be acceptable or suitable
- a creature that comes from somewhere other than the planet Earth

Adding those two definition is not hard to turn this word into the synonym of "monster from outer space. And yes, the word "alien" was used in such context before, i.e. in the 1954 [Killers from Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047149/) where you have rubber monsters attacking Earth and indeed called Aliens.

Comment: [google books](http://books.google.com) lets you restrict the date range (after trying your search terms, you should see a bar with 'search tools', click that to filter by date), so you can restrict it to something prior to 1979 using search terms like "alien" and "monster", or "alien" and "creature", or "alien" and "planet", etc. (not just 'alien' alone though, as that will mainly gives books in which groups of people or their customs are referred to as alien). [Here's an example from 1962](http://books.google.com/books?id=SC5WrqyPXjMC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=alien+monster), for example.

Comment: But that definition is from a contemporary dictionary. The contemporary meaning of *alien* is influenced by such movies as the one OP is referring to. I checked the 1913 dictionary, and there was no reference to extraterrestrials for the word. The best way to answer this question is to check a 1975 dictionary or encyclopedia for the word "alien". Your 1954 example is relevant, but it doesn't necesarrily mean that the word was *commonly* used that way at the time.

Comment: @Fiksdal The best way to answer this question is to check a historical dictionary, i.e., the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: @user14111 Cool, I didn't know about this. I'll check it out right now.

Comment: [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alien) also translates this word as "extraterrestrial"

Comment: I guess my question should have been posed a different way, "If you walked up to the average person on the street in 1977 and asked them, what is the first thing that comes to my when i ask you to think of an alien - would it be be 'a monster from outer space' or 'a foreigner in a sovereign land without proper visas.'" Ideally, I would like someone born before 1960 to weigh in, as they would have been an adult in 1979, but I suspect many on this site don't fit that category. Another way of posing the question would be "Was a title of 'Alien' for a space monster movie novel and clever" in 1979?

Comment: @hank mitchell - The google book search I mentioned does so plenty of older books that used "alien" for "extraterrestrial" in a way that suggested they assumed their audience would be familiar with this usage. But people might be more likely to have sources handy about the history of word usage at the [English language stack exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

The first place to look for *expert* answers to questions of first-use in English is [the OED](http://www.oed.com) (£); it has the "An (intelligent) being from another planet; an extraterrestrial" meaning from 1931, with adjectival use from 1929.

So, to "was a title of Alien for a space monster movie novel ... in 1979?" the answer is definitely **no**.

I don't know about "clever".